# ggplot2 labels for color=factor(foo)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a hard time with labels on a ggplot2 plot. Here's a similar plot from the examples page:

```
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
mt + facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales = "free")
```

How would I define a list of labels for factor(cyl)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in the `labels` argument to the colour scale:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete(breaks = c("4", "6", "8"),
                        labels = c("Four", "Six", "Eight"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it in the `data.frame` itself:

```
mtcars$cyl_factor <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c('Four', 'Six', 'Eight'))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl_factor)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl, scales = "free")
```